# Bluetooth connectivity in Python

Tags: python

How can I find nearby Bluetooth devices using Python, with a Bluetooth adaptor?

Answer (score 1):

You could use either of the following libraries:

- [PyBluez](http://pybluez.googlecode.com/)
- [LightBlue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i used Pybluez on windows but it gives me an error.....saying bluetooth adapter not found....i have installed the driver for adapter also i.e Bluesoliel....what should i do

Answer (score 0):

BlueSoleil stack isn't compatible with PyBluez. I ended up uninstalling BlueSoleil, restarted the machine (as per the post-uninstall prompt), and then configured my USB BT adapter for using the Microsoft BT Stack. After that, I didn't have any issues with the "Adapter not found" error message.

Note that figuring out how to get your BT dongle to use the Microsoft stack was a pain in the rear end :) Some googling around brought me to this page - http://www.shootingsoftware.com/Widcomm.htm

The author discusses a patch for a ".inf" file, but you might want to explore other options before you try this ... keep this method as your last resort.